# making bash script fail and exit when using a failed left AND operator operation

Tags: bash

From the docs apparently using set -e is not enough in a bash script to have it fail and exit when inside there are 2 operations tied with && operator of which first fails.

So in essence if I have:
false && true 
inside a bash script with set -e what else do I need to make the script fail and exit without continuing ?

Comment: If first condition fails then second condition after `&&` won't be evaluated.

Comment: See [BashFAQ #105](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105#Exercises) -- `set -e` is nonportable even between minor versions of the same shell, with behavior full of corner cases. Don't use it. Don't rely on it.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) - what are you *actually* trying to accomplish?

Comment: `set -e; { false && true; } || false`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following construct will stop the script if either of your previous commands fail.  I use it all the time in lieu of an `if` statement:

```
{ false && true; } || {
   echo 1>&2 "? predicate expression failed"
   exit 1
}
```

You can also exit if the expression succeeds:

```
{ true && true; } && {
  echo "Operation complete! Exiting"
  exit 0
}
```

The brackets (or you can use a subshell, but that is less efficient) are not strictly needed, but make things a bit clearer.

Comment: `{ true && true; } || { ...` avoids the efficiency hit that comes with the subshell that parens create.

Comment: ...it's not only an efficiency cost but a correctness cost as well; `{ somevar=$(somecommand) && whatever; } || { ....` doesn't discard the value of `somevar`, but `(somevar=$(somecommand) && ...) || ...` does.

Comment: BTW, I usually define a function `die() { echo "$*" >&2; exit 1; }`, and then can just `{ a && b; } || die "some error occurred"`; cleaner and more readable than a compound command for each error case.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, good points, all.  I updated my answer to primarily suggest using brackets rather than parens.

Comment: Caveat: Brackets are more picky about whitespace and newlines. You really do need the space after the `{` and either a semicolon or newline before the `}` in `{ false && true; }`.

Answer (score 2):

#### `&&` (and even `if`) would be useless if `set -e` behaved this way.

Consider the following code in a context where `errexit` is *not* enabled:

```
check_if_we_need_foo && do_foo
proceed_with_other_stuff
```

...which is close to:

```
if check_if_we_need_foo; then
  do_foo
fi
proceed_with_other_stuff
```

If `set -e` behaved the way you're asking for, the codepath where `check_if_we_need_foo` returns false, `do_foo` is skipped, and `proceed_with_other_stuff` then happens *would be impossible to write*, because any falsey exit status (even one meant to indicate a boolean false rather than an error) would cause the script to immediately exit.

Moreover, `&&` would have no meaning different from that of `;` or a newline!

What good is an `if` where the `true` branch is the only version that doesn't result in an immediate exit?

---

#### Thus, `set -e` does not act on exit status of "checked" commands.

If you want to distinguish between an error (that should trigger an exit) and a logical false (that should cause the "else" branch of an if, or in the case of an `&&`, the content on the right-hand side to not be executed), you need to write that code yourself, by inspecting the exit status as appropriate (assuming they're distinguishable). If they're not distinguishable, there's your answer -- making a distinction is impossible.

Comment: Thanks for helping, I know how and why set -e behaves, just wanted a quick way to exit the script in case the first operation (function call etc) fails. Wanted a quick way to have this because I have several scripts to modify and did not want to make a large intrusion. Thanks anyway.

Comment: `... || die "error message here"`, after defining such a function, is generally what I recommend folks use *instead of* `set -e`. Better to do something explicit and audit for its presence than rely on a highly haphazard half-measure.